# Undefined method when saving an instance of my "Stop" model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails App consists of touristic Routes. Each route has many stops and waypoints and stops have categories.

Waypoints are just the intermediate model between routes and stops because stops can belong to many routes.

So, when i try to save a Stop, i get the error:

```
undefined method `category' for #<Stop:0x007fa067acea90>
```

And the " if @stop.save" line is highlighted in red:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @stop.save
    Waypoint.create(route_id: params[:route_id] , stop_id: @stop.id)
    #print out category id or name here
    category = params[:category]
```

In my stops controller i have this on create:

```
def create
@stop = Stop.new(stop_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @stop.save
    Waypoint.create(route_id: params[:route_id] , stop_id: @stop.id)
    #print out category id or name here
    category = params[:category]
    #once printed save it (stop category)
    StopCategory.create(category_id: category, stop_id:  @stop.id)
    format.html { redirect_to @stop, notice: 'Stop was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location:@stop }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @stop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

And on my waypoints controller i have this on create:

```
    def create
    @waypoint = Waypoint.create(waypoint_params)

    redirect_to @waypoint.route

end
```

This is the stop model:

```
class Stop < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :description, length: { maximum: 140 }
validates :category, presence: true
#Image Uploader
mount_uploader  :stop_image, StopImageUploader

#Relationship with stops and waypoints
has_many :waypoints
has_many :routes, through: :waypoints

# Relationship with categories
has_many :stop_categories
has_many :categories, through: :stop_categories
```

end

And this is the view where the form is :

```
<h2>Create a new stop:</h2><br>
    <%= form_for(@stop) do |f| %>
      <% if @stop.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@stop.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this stop from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @stop.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :name %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </div>

        <select name="category" id=" " >

            <option value="" disabled selected> Select a Category </option>

            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
            <option value="<%= category.id %>"> <%= category.name %> </option>
            <% end %>
        </select>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :description %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :description %>
        </div>


        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :stop_image %><br>
            <%= f.file_field :stop_image %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :stop_lat %><br>
            <%= f.number_field :stop_lat, :class => 'text_field', :step => 'any' %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :stop_long %><br>
            <%= f.number_field :stop_long, :class => 'text_field', :step => 'any' %>
        </div>

            <%= hidden_field_tag  :route_id,  params[:id]    %>
        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
    <% end %> 


    <h2>Add existing stop</h2>
    <br>
    <%= form_for(@waypoint) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :stop_id %><br>
            <%= f.number_field :stop_id %>
        </div>
        <%= f.hidden_field  :route_id    %>

        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
    <% end %> 

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_route_path(@route) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', routes_path %>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        </div>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that `@stop.save` raises the error suggests, that the error is in the `Stop` model. Please include that and a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have added the stop model now.

Im sorry I dont know which one is the stack trace... i see three in the error page:

Application Trace , Framework Trace and Full Trace ?

Comment: `validates :category, presence: true`. Your model doesn't know category, because it has catgegories thourgh stop_categories

Comment: I tried this two variations and both returned an error:
stop_categories and i also tried stop_category.Which one should be right ?

Comment: The stop is being created on the Route show view, maybe that is relevant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a 'category' attribute in your Stop model? If not, then the following doesn't make sense:

```
validates :category, presence: true
```

That is where it's probably failing.

If you want to validate the presence of categories, you need to replace that check with something like this:

```
validate :has_categories

def has_categories # make this private
  if categories.blank?
    # add errors here
  end
end
```

The following might also work:

```
validates :categories, presence: true
```

Comment: Actually i dont have a category attribute in my stop model, i do have a stop_category model and that has a category_id and stop_id...So im guessing if I want to validate presence of category i have to do what you suggest...

Thanks!

Comment: If it works, remember to mark my response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Stop model, you should replace the line

```
validates :category, presence: true
```

with

```
validates :categories, presence: true
```

because the validator takes the attribute/association name as argument, not the model name of the association.

Your association is called `categories`, so that's what you need to perform the validation on.

Comment: Thanks, when i do that i get : NoMethodError in Stops#create. And it highlights the line where the each is here:___________________________________


<option value="" disabled selected> Select a Category </option>
   
           <% @categories.each do |category| %>
           <option value="<%= category.id %>"> <%= category.name %> </option>
         <% end %>
       </select>______________________________________________

But the thing is that the form for creating the stop is in the routes show view.

Comment: That is a completely different issue. You did not set `@categories` in the controller. Use `@stop.categories` instead